# Change how CSS border edges meet?

Tags: html, css, border

[image: boder a and b]

**How css border edges look: A**

**How I'd like them to look: B**

How do I accomplish this?

I've tried using "outer shadow" but the resulting left border is noticeably blurry even when blur is set to 0. open to other solutions, though preferably without adding additional elements.

Comment: Given that you don't like the usual alternative (although I've never seen any blurriness...perhaps you're doing it wrong?) and the other limitation(s) you impose...I'd say the answer is NO.

Comment: You could avoid using '*additional* elements,' but without at least using pseudo-elements the answer remains a firm (but unfortunate) 'no.'

Comment: It would be possible to achieve this using `box-shadow` or `border-image`, but not with a standard `border`.

Comment: Check out my answer, happy coding. :)

Comment: Also, if you're looking for a black border on the left and right-hand side, and a red one on the top and bottom, I've updated my answer. If you could mark it as correct that'd be appreciated buddy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit, you can use:

```
box-shadow: 0 5px red;
```

This shows both techniques being used on one DIV:

```
<div id="square" style="height: 50px; width: 50px; border-left: 5px solid black; border-top: 5px solid red;box-shadow: 0 5px red;"></div>
```

If you are looking for a black border on the two sides and a red on the top and bottom:

```
<div id="square" style="height: 50px; width: 50px; border-left: 5px solid black; border-right: 5px solid black;box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px red, 0px -5px 0px red;"></div>
```